# Python: better iteration workflow using Beautifulsoup and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, iteration

folks

I'm working on extracting some sentences from a document and tying to make a dataframe with BeautifulSoup and pandas as follows. There are some iterations so I think it would be written in a better way like a pro. Could you help with developing these lines of code? Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

t1 = bs.find_all('h1')[1].text.replace('_room1',"")
t2 = bs.find_all('h1')[2].text.replace('_room1',"") 
t3 = bs.find_all('h1')[3].text.replace('_room1',"")
t4 = bs.find_all('h1')[4].text.replace('_room1',"")

p1 = bs.find_all('p')[3].text
p2 = bs.find_all('p')[4].text + bs.find_all('p')[5].text + bs.find_all('p')[6].text + bs.find_all('p')[7].text
p3 = bs.find_all('p')[8].text
p4 = bs.find_all('p')[9].text


data = {t1: p1,
      t2: p2,
      t3: p3,
      t4: p4}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])

df
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. The use of magic numbers (e.g. 3, 4, 8, 9) is not great, but it may be the simplest way to solve the problem, since many sites don't go out of their way to make it easy to scrape them. Is there a specific problem you're looking for help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just getting the text from your H1's and P's in one go:

```
h1s = [h1.text for h1 in bs.select('h1')[:4]]
ps =  [p.text for p in bs.select('p')]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    h1: p
    for h1, p in zip(h1s, [ps[3], ''.join(ps[4:7]), ps[8], ps[9])
}).T
```